# Why were demons created at the end of Friday?

Tags: shabbat, creation, sheidim-demons

Why were demons created at the end of Friday? Seems to me that this time of creation is the most auspicious. Why create something negative then?

Comment: Do you really think a good God is capable to create evil unseen “forces”?

Comment: @TurkHill Do you really think that G-d is incapable of creating whatever forces He chooses to?

Comment: @Meir Maimonides said that God is good and only does good.

Comment: @TurkHill And? G-d also punishes when necessary, which is also good, as a corrective.

Comment: @TurkHill beautiful point, and perhaps that's exactly why Hashem didn't create these demons' bodies, just their spiritual components, as a chesed, an act of pure good

Comment: @RabbiKaii  This is possible, but I am not sure what a component is.

Comment: @TurkHill Isaiah 45:7?

Answer (score 2):

Midrash Shmuel (Avos 5:5) writes the following:

> ואפשר עוד לומר כי אלו הדברים נבראו בערב שבת בין השמשות לפי שכבר חטא
> אדם הראשון וגברו החיצונים והקליפות וראה השי"ת לברא אלו העשרה דברים
> לתועלתם של ישראל, כי מבלעדם לא היתה להם תקומה, ועל דרך מה שאמרו ז"ל
> שבא השבת והגין על אדם הראשון, כן נאמר בנידון דידן שהמתין עד זמן השמשות
> כי הזמן עצמו יגן על ישראל, לפי שישראל מוסיפין אותו מחול על הקודש,
> ובאותו הזמן נבראו אלו הדברים לתועלתם של ישראל... ויש אומרים אף
> המזיקין, כי לתועלתם של ישראל נבראו, שהמזיקין נפרעין מן הרשעים סמאל
> וסיעתו ונשארה נפשם מתוקנת אחר שפורעים את חובם...

The first point he makes is that all the 10 items that were created *bein hashmashos* were only necessary after Adam sinned on Friday, which led to the 'forces of evil' being given more power within the world. This itself may be an answer to why the Demons were created then.

However, he continues to explain why they had to be specifically *bein hashmashos*, because all these creations were for the purpose of Klal Yisroel's continuity, and are instrinsically connected to Shabbos which was a protection to Adam from the consequences of his sin. Demons too were created to provide retribution to the wicked, which provides *tikkun*.

Answer (score 0):

[Midrash says](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.7.5) that Hashem started creating demons and when shabbos came he stopped, that's why they're incomplete creatures. To teach us when shabbos comes we stop our work, even in the middle of something.

This, therefore doesn't contradict the auspiciousness of shabbos, but rather teaches it!

Comment: And on top of that, for all we know demons weren’t supposed to be, well, demons. If Gd was in the middle of creating them and He stopped midway for Shabbos, clearly they might have been intended to be something else

Comment: @CuriousYid I wouldn't say that. It's not as though G-d didn't know how to plan in advance how long it would take, after all...

Comment: @Meir See Bartenura in Avos chapter 5.

Comment: a reference to the midrash would be an improvement to the answer.

Comment: @Meir that's a moot point as there are plenty of examples of this in Torah, each with its own lesson. Perhaps the lesson here is that if demons also had bodies, they'd be much more dangerous, so Hashem did this deliberately, as a chesed, and at the same time teaching how auspicious Shabbat is

Comment: @CuriousYid pinging you to also see what I wrote. Perhaps the opposite, demons were supposed to be even more demonic! BH they were created without their bodies...

Comment: @RabbiKaii I like that interpretation thanks!

Comment: @RabbiKaii You can feel free to edit it.

Comment: וישבות ביום השביעי - ונראה לומר על דרך מה שאמרו ז"ל כי בריות נבראו ערב שבת עם חשיכה ולא הספיקו לגמור בריאת גופם עד שקדש היום, והן הם המזיקים. ויש לנו להשכיל זאת איך יוצדק ליאמר בערך הבורא יתע"ש שלא הספיק לגמור וכו', הלא דבר ידוע לכל כי כהרף עין יכול לברא עולמות כלם... אכן הכונה היא כי רצה ה' להודיע עוצם מעלות יום המכובד, כי הלא תדע שישתנה הדבר בין מלאכה שהתחיל בה ואין הפסד למלאכה שכבר התחיל בה ותפסד אם לא יגמרו אותה, וכאן הודיענו הכתוב כי מלבד שלא התחיל מלאכה אחרת אלא אפילו במלאכה שהתחיל בה כשקדש היום גם כן שבת מלגמור אותה, הגם שנפסד המלאכה שהתחיל בה הפסד שאין אחריו תיקון(אור החיים בראשית ב:ב)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a common thread that links all the things that were created in this time.

> עֲשָׂרָה דְבָרִים נִבְרְאוּ בְּעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת בֵּין הַשְּׁמָשׁוֹת,
> וְאֵלּוּ הֵן, פִּי הָאָרֶץ, וּפִי הַבְּאֵר, וּפִי הָאָתוֹן,
> וְהַקֶּשֶׁת, וְהַמָּן, וְהַמַּטֶּה, וְהַשָּׁמִיר, וְהַכְּתָב,
> וְהַמִּכְתָּב, וְהַלּוּחוֹת. וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים, אַף הַמַּזִּיקִין,
> וּקְבוּרָתוֹ שֶׁל משֶׁה, וְאֵילוֹ שֶׁל אַבְרָהָם אָבִינוּ. וְיֵשׁ
> אוֹמְרִים, אַף צְבָת בִּצְבָת עֲשׂוּיָה:
>
> Ten things were created on
> the eve of the Sabbath at twilight, and these are they: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_Loew_ben_Bezalel) the mouth
> of the earth, [2] the mouth of the well, [3] the mouth of the donkey,
> [4] the rainbow, [5] the manna, [6] the staff [of Moses], [7] the
> shamir, [8] the letters, [9] the writing, [10] and the tablets. And
> some say: also the demons, the grave of Moses, and the ram of Abraham,
> our father. And some say: and also tongs, made with tongs.

All these things were supernatural. The 6 Days of Creation were the creation of the physical world. These items exist within the physical world, yet transcend the physical order by essence of being miraculous. Therefore, these things could only be created *bein hashmashos* - a time linking the 6 Days of the Creation and Shabbos, which represents spirituality within the physical world.

The problem with this explanation - and many other explanations of this Mishna - is the tongs, which has no supernatural element at all.

---

EDIT: I found a source to this in the [Maharal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_Loew_ben_Bezalel) (Derech Chaim, Avos):

> ופירוש משנה הזאת, מה שהוצרכו חכמים לומר, כי יש דברים נבראו בערב שבת
> בין השמשות, דבר זה, הזמן של ערב שבת בין השמשות הוא הגורם, וזה מפני כי
> שאר בין השמשות שהוא לא יום ולא לילה...
> אבל בערב שבת בין השמשות מצד שהוא בין השמשות של קדושה הוא
> יותר במדרגה משאר ימי הטבע, ואי אפשר לומר שלא נברא בו דבר, שהרי אינו
> שבת גמור, ואי אפשר שנברא בו כמו שאר ימי בראשית, שהרי אינו חול, **ולפיכך
> נבראו בו דברים שהם למעלה מן הטבע, ואינם טבעיים כמו שנבראו בששת ימי
> המעשה,** וכל זה בין השמשות של ערב שבת הוא למעלה מששת ימי הטבע, כמו שהשבת
> מצד קדושתו הוא למעלה מן ששת ימי בראשית, ולפיכך בין השמשות של ערב שבת
> אי אפשר שיהיה בלא בריאה, כי עדיין לא נכנס השבת שהוא שביתה גמורה ואי
> אפשר שיהיה נברא בו הדברים הטבעיים שהרי הוא יותר במדריגה מששת ימי
> המעשה, ולפיכך נבראו בו אלו דברים שאינם טבעיים לגמרי והם קרובים אל
> הטבע, כי כל אלו הם דברים גשמיים ומצד זה טבעיים, ומצד שאינם כמו שאר
> דברים טבעיים הם יוצאים מן הטבע.